# Can't Uninstall PCSX2

Tags: uninstall, 21.10, pcsx2

I know this is about PCSX2 but since it's still on Ubuntu. But anyways I need help with uninstalling PCSX2 from my laptop. I am currently running the latest version of Ubuntu at the moment of me typing this. I'm a complete newbie to Linux literally just installed it today and I was trying to use PCSX2 but no matter what I do I couldn't get it to recognize my Xbox controller. I am running verison 1.7.0-0 GIT and before making this post I did look up on how to uninstall it and every time I entered in the command it told me too. It kept saying I didn't have it on my computer even though I do. I just need help with uninstalling it. Can anyone help?

[This is proof that I actually do have it installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atFmZ.png)

[This is what happens every time I try to install it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXwT.png)

---

The output of `which pcsx2` is empty.

and `which PCSX2` is:

```
/usr/games/PCSX2
```

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/games/PCSX2
pcsx2-unstable: /usr/games/PCSX2
```

Comment: It is maybe a snap.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `which pcsx2` and `which PCSX2` to the original question. I prepared two TODO blocks for the actual output.

Comment: Open terminal, please, execute command `which pcsx2` , copy its output, paste to the question. Then do the same for second command - `which PCSX2` .

Comment: Oh ok well the first command you posted did nothing. But the second showed this "/usr/games/PCSX2"

Comment: Then we need output of `dpkg -S /usr/games/PCSX2`  .

Comment: Did that and it showed this "pcsx2-unstable: /usr/games/PCSX2"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131963/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-corny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During chat session we discovered that it was installed from [PCSX2 Daily Builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epcsx2-team/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2-daily). To remove the PPA and packages use below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily
sudo apt-get autopurge pcsx2-unstable
sudo apt-get autopurge pcsx2
```